# поделитесь опытом как сверстать такие ромбики вложенные в блок?

Tags: html5, css3, вёрстка

```css
.section__blocksocial {
  width: 280px;
  /*при фикс. ширине работает но нужна ширина 23.33% */
  height: 294px;
  float: left;
  background: rgba(247, 247, 247, .8);
  margin: 0 1.66% 1.66% 0;
}

.blocksocial {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: rgba(150, 150, 150, .1);
}

.blocksocial:nth-child(1) {
  margin: 35% 12.5% 0% 9%;
}

.blocksocial:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 35% 12.5% 0 0;
}

.blocksocial:nth-child(3) {
  margin: 35% 0% 0 0%;
}

.blocksocial:nth-child(4) {
  margin: -2.5% 0% 0% 25%;
}

.blocksocial:nth-child(5) {
  margin: -2.5% 0% 0 12.5%;
}

.blocksocial__fbook {
  display: block;
  /* margin: 0 1,25% 1,25% 2,5%; */
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg)
}

.blocksocial__twiter {
  display: block;
  /* margin: 0 1.25% 1.25% 1.25%;*/
}

.blocksocial__pint {
  display: block;
  /* margin: 0 1.25% 1.25% 2.5%;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="section__blocksocial">
  <div class="blocksocial blocksocial__fbook"></div>
  <div class="blocksocial blocksocial__twiter"></div>
  <div class="blocksocial blocksocial__pint"></div>
  <div class="blocksocial blocksocial__google"></div>
  <div class="blocksocial blocksocial__inst"></div>
</div>
```

[image: ромбики для иконок социальных сетей]

делал таким образом:
сверстал пять блоков потом используя свойство transform: rotate(45deg);
но блоки наложились один на другой

Comment: что значит "наложились один на другой" ? покажи html и css (нажми кнопку "править" под вопросом и добавь)

Comment: Можно пованговать и предположить, что не правильно установлены или вовсе отсутствуют координаты точки, относительно которой происходит трансформация - `transform-origin`

Comment: собственно? а в чем проблема? им не хватает места, вот они и скатываются? тут либо фиксированная ширина, либо другой подход к коду...

Comment: + у вас код мягко говоря страшный и закостылиный) что вы будите делать когда еще одну иконку вставить нужно? писать еще `.blocksocial:nth-child(N)`? сей подход не годится... это все нужно решить с помощью `.blocksocial:nth-child(odd)` and `.blocksocial:nth-child(even)`.

Comment: поэтому и задал этот вопрос, может кто уже с таким сталкивался, я впервые с ромбиками столкнулся, вот и пытаюсь выполнить это, возможно кому то тоже будет полезно подумать над этим) т.к. ничего не нашел

Comment: @maks, воспользуйтесь моим вариантом, я написал в ответе)

Comment: спасибо вам Руслан, я уже просмотрел, все четко

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот код - https://jsfiddle.net/twschd36/

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.cfix::after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
 clear: both;
}

.cont {
 padding: 15px;
}

.romb {
 background-color: #000;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 float: left;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.romb:nth-child(even) {
 margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont cfix">
   <div class="romb"></div>
   <div class="romb"></div>
   <div class="romb"></div>
   <div class="romb"></div>
   <div class="romb"></div>
   <div class="romb"></div>
</div>
```